# How to reduce the noise of the mini printing machine?

Tags: sound, printing

I am staying in a house that the wall is quite thin, that is why I bought a printing machine.
However, after buying, I found out that my printing machine works a little bit noisy. I am wondering how to reduce the noise from this printing machine?

p/s: i am using HP DeskJet 2131

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many, if not most, minimalist printers are manufactured to keep material cost low for competitive pricing and so do not have any more costly provision to be silent in operation. Fan noise tends to be loud and since it is intermittent perception makes it seem even more so.

**Schedule Hack**: Rather than working to make an inexpensive machine quiet, which could compromise its proper operation, consider operating the unit when noise is least objectionable such as daytime, **during business hours**, say.

Mealtimes are normally noisy for the average person so few would notice your addition to the urban din.

Organize your printing so that you get everything done at one convenient time, all things considered.

Chances are what you need to print is not so urgent that a slight delay would have dire consequences.

Good luck.

Comment: Further to @Stan’s answer, you may be able to set up print queues on your computer. One of them could be normal, that points right away, and another could be set up to hold documents and print them during business hours. Then if you’re working late at night, say, the docs would be held until 8am (or whatever you configure) and then would print without further intervention when that time arrives.  You can have multiple print queues for one printer.  The particulars of the setup depend on which OS you are using.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the good [answer from Stan](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/a/25044/28188) you could find somewhere to stand the printer that deadens the sound, for example a small piece of carpet underneath. A table top often amplifies the noise of anything stood on it.

You also have it placed right next to a wall. If the wall is of a thin material such as plasterboard that too can amplify the sound through to other rooms, in that case stand it further from the wall.